# М'якоть - росіянізм чи питоме слово?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники, правопис

У вірші Аліни Олійник [Джем](http://maysterni.com/publication.php?id=69860) є такі слова:

> Перестигли вірші, наче **м’якоть** грейпфрута,
>
> В їхній терпкості – правда й відвертості смак.
>
> Витискається сік з гострих слів, мов отрута,
>
> Мов наркотик - посіяний істини мак.

Цікавить саме ***"м’якоть"***.

У [Малому академічному словнику](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/29956/%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C) є це слово (звідси мені видається, що це росіянізм).

Однак у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/m.jakotj) теж воно є:

> **М'Я́КОТЬ**, і, жін. Те саме, що ***м'якуш***.

Також на сайтах часто використовують слово "м'якіть". Наприклад, у статті ["У гарбузі корисна і м'якіть, і насіння, і навіть стебло..."](http://dobryjlikar.com/article/201710/5107-garbuzi-korysna-myakit-nasinnya-navit-steblo).

Таке ж слово знайшла і в [Англо-українському поурочному словнику](https://studfiles.net/preview/5009304/page:60/):

> wood pulp – дерев’яна серцевина, **м’якіть**

Оскільки СУМ-11 - це видання 1970-80 рр., цікавить, чи, випадково, слово м'якоть не є росіянізмом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [Етимологічному словнику т. 3., с. 547](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) знаходимо, що м’якоть, м’якуш, м’якіть – одного походження і ці слова є спільними для слов’янських мов, тому це слово не є росіянізмом:
[image]